# owlready2 AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'CREATE_NO_WINDOW'

Tags: python, anaconda, owlready

System: Windows 10

IDE: PyCharm with conda environment

When i try to import owlready2

```
from owlready2 import *
```

return this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\........\lib\site-packages\owlready2\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from owlready2.reasoning       import *
  File "C:\Users\.......\owlready2\reasoning.py", line 84, in <module>
    _subprocess_kargs = { "creationflags" : subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW }
AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'CREATE_NO_WINDOW'
python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can i resolve this issue?
Thank you.